# Connecting to a WebSocket in Golang fails with bad handshake

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a websocket in Golang using github.com/gorilla/websocket library but it's failing with a bad handshake.

Golang code :

```
    c, resp, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(resp.Status)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    _ = c
```

Output :

```
200 OK
websocket: bad handshake
```

I also tried connecting to the same socket in python using socketio and it works.

Python code:

```
import socketio
sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect(WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT, transports = 'websocket')

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("I'm connected!")
```

Output :

```
I'm connected!
```

Comment: @Zombo I know that. But why does it work when I do it with python?

Comment: The Go and Python programs are doing something different, but it's difficult determine what that is from the information in the question.   To debug the problem, print resp.Status and the contents of resp.Body.

Comment: I'm getting same error when trying to create multiple clients in many goroutines

Comment: Is there any solution you got regarding this issue, if yes please let us know it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

See [What Socket.IO is not](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not):

> Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket for transport when possible, it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain WebSocket server either.

In Go you are using [Gorilla Websockets](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) which is a standard Websocket client. Your Python example appears to be using [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#socketio.Client.connect) which is an implementation of Socket.IO.

As per the above quote the two are not directly compatible. I suspect your server is using Socket.IO and, as per the above quote, "a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect".

Comment: What is the solution for this ?@brits

Comment: @MukulVarshney Use websockets on both sides, or Socket.IO on both sides (i.e. pick one protocol or the other!).